# VBA Shell command not running (Python Script)

Tags: python, vba, shell

I wrote PYthon script that works when run from normal command prompt but the same command is not working when run via VBA code.

I check that waitOnReturn would be able to help me with that, but even using waitReturn, my python script seems to be not working from VBA, and also no error pop ups.

```
Sub Exec()
Dim objShell As Object
Dim PythonExec, PythonScript As String
Dim waitOnReturn As Boolean: waitOnReturn = True
Dim windowStyle As Integer: windowStyle = 1

Set objShell = VBA.CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")

PythonExec = """C:\Users\123\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\python.exe"""
PythonScript = "C:\Users\123\Run.py"

 objShell.Run PythonExec & " " & PythonScript, windowStyle, True

End Sub
```

Could you guys please help me with that problem? I have no idea about what I'm missing.

Comment: Can you edit the question to include `Run.py`?

Answer (score 0):

At starts it did not work for me either, a window was popping up and instantly disappearing.

What solved it for me was to use """ around all the paths.

like this:

```
PythonExec = """C:\Users\123\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\python.exe"""

PythonScript = """C:\Users\123\Run.py"""
```

Finally you can see the error message if you run the script using cmd, like that:

```
objShell.Run "cmd /k" & " " & PythonExec & " " & PythonScript
```

Even if the script fails to run, you will have the info regarding why had it failed