# How to run a Python Script with VBA?

Tags: python, excel, vba, pycharm

I am trying to run a Python Script through VBA, but it doesn´t work. It just opens and closes CMD Prompt.

Code in VBA:

```
Sub python()


Dim objShell As Object
Dim PythonExePath, PythonScriptPath As String
ActiveWorkbook.Save
ChDir ActiveWorkbook.Path

Set objShell = VBA.CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")

    PythonExePath = """C:\Users\IDDavidRosset\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\python.exe"""
    PythonScriptPath = """C:\Users\IDDavidRosset\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\ID.py"""
    
    objShell.Run PythonExePath & PythonScriptPath

End Sub
```

Code in Python:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pyautogui
import pandas as pd
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
df = pd.read_excel(r'C:\Users\IDDavidRosset\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\test2\Teste.xlsm')
```

When I run VBA it just opens and closes command prompt

Comment: Have you looked in the Event Viewer for errors, i suspect it has to do with permissions of some sort, running layers of services like rundll.dll and who knows what else.  Use Process Explorer - Sysinternals to see what runs.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54936506/vba-shell-command-not-running-python-script shows how to keep the cmd open in case there are any errors there.

Answer (score 0):

Executable path and script path should be separated with space:

```
objShell.Run PythonExePath & " " & PythonScriptPath
```

Comment: Tried that it didn´t work